# не работает машина состояний в чате телеграм, не устанавливается состояние для пользователя в чате

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Господа эксперты, прошу помочь. Пишу бота на aiogram для одной компании, его суть - пользователи отправляют репорты, они падают в чат с модераторами, далее, при одобрении, падают в следующий чат. Так вот все работало до недавнего момента, почему перестало - понятия не имею. Суть проблемы - при рассмотрении репорта, пользователь, начавший рассмотрение, попадает в машину состояний, где в одном единственном состоянии проходит все рассмотрение(сделано, чтобы другие админы не могли продолжить рассматривать то, что начал рассматривать кто-то другой). Так вот при попадании в состояние, обработчик(на callback'ах) тупо не срабатывает, хотя буквально пару-тройку неделю назад все работало замечательно. Опытным путем выяснил, что бот целенаправленно игнорирует человека, попавшего в стейт, а так же, что проблема именно в состояниях. Уже встречался с проблемой состояний в чатах, но тогда проблема решилась добавление бота в список администраторов, сейчас же такой фокус уже не прокатывает. собственно вот целевой код. Сюда пользователь попадает, нажав на кнопку, прикрепленную к сообщению, этот обработчик срабатывает

```
async def start_rewiew(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):

    await call.answer('start_rewiew')
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    markup.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Одобрить', callback_data='accept'),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отклонить', callback_data='deny'),
    )

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        try:
            var = data['elements']
        except:
            data['elements'] = []
            data['lister'] = None

    await call.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=markup)
    await state.set_state('report_rewiew')
```

в обработчик ниже пользователь уже не попадает, однако если в регистраторе хендлера убрать state='report_rewiew', то он уже попадает туда.

```
async def accept_rewiew(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await call.answer('accept_rewiew')
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    markup.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Одобрить несколько', callback_data='Одобрено несколько'),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Одобрить все', callback_data='Одобрено'),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='descry'),
    )

    await call.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=markup)
```

ниже код регистрации хендлеров(не всех)

```
def register(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(start_rewiew, text='descry', state='*')
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(accept_rewiew, text='accept', state='report_rewiew')
```

собственно вопрос. Почему не устанавливается устанавливается состояние?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решилась изменением версии aiogram. на версии 2.9 машина состояний в групповом чате не работала(может я криво написал, не знаю), после долгих поисков и общения с другом у него все работало у меня нет и выяснилось, что у него версия aiogram 2.25, а у меня 2.9. чтобы откатить версию использовал такие команды

```
pip uninstall aiogram
pip install aiogram==2.25
```

где 2.25 - требуемая версия